# D3Js similar labels/duplicates use the to same x value

Tags: html, svg, d3.js

I'm using the following code. The issue is if my labels have the same value the values join themselves to the existing x value label.

```
output = [
  { day : "M", frequency : 1},
  { day : "M", frequency : 2}
  { day : "T", frequency : 3}
  { day : "T", frequency : 4}
  { day : "M", frequency : 5}
]

var margin = {top: 10, right: 10, bottom: 30, left: 10},
    width = $('#dayhour').width() - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 240 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
var xValue = function(d) { return d.day; }, // data -> value
    xScale = d3.scale.ordinal().rangeRoundBands([0, width], .1), // value -> display
    xMap = function(d) { return xScale(xValue(d)); }, // data -> display
    xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(xScale).orient("bottom");

var yValue = function(d) { return d.frequency; }, // data -> value
    yScale = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]), // value -> display
    yMap = function(d) { return yScale(yValue(d)); }, // data -> display
    yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(yScale).orient("left");

var svg = d3.select("body").append('svg')
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

  xScale.domain(output.map(xValue));
  yScale.domain([0, d3.max(output, yValue)]);

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis);

  svg.selectAll(".bar")
      .data(output)
      .enter().append("rect")
      .attr("class", "bar")
      .attr("x", xMap)
      .style("stroke", '#A1B9CC')
      .style("stroke-width", '1')
      .style("fill", "#CFDCE5")
      .attr("width", xScale.rangeBand)
      .attr("y", yMap)
      .attr("height", function(d) { return height - yMap(d); });
```

After reading a couple of answers I tried changing the xMap function to this but it didn't really help.

```
xMap = function(d,i) { console.log(i); return i * xScale(xValue(d)); }
```

I'm sure the fix to this is something minor but I just want to display the `output` as bars in the same order as the array & not have the same bars using the same x axis position if the `day` value is a duplicate.

If possible could the individual change be pointed out so that others can also benefit from this?
There are a lot of posts on this but they are not very helpful because they are so localized.

Comment: D3 is largely data-driven. So if the labels don't matter or should be distinct, you should make them so. That is, have another attribute in your data that gives the labels/values for the scale.

Comment: How would I do this i'm new to d3js. Thats also what I thought but I can't figure why it interprets it this way

Comment: Are the labels interpreted as keys with xMap?

Comment: You're using an ordinal scale. Scales map input to output values, i.e. the same input value will produce the same output value. Hence my suggestion that if you want them mapped to different outputs, use different inputs.

Comment: Ahh, I see. I cant change the inputs because most are blank. I'm doing a 1am to 11pm sort of thing but its a bit clustering to include all the values, so I leave some blank. Which of these functions would I need to change so it would work, which is the scaling function? Do you know of good tutes on this you could suggest to me?

Comment: As I've said, you need to change the *data* you're passing to the functions -- something like an ID would do. The tutorials at the D3 website are a good place to start.

Comment: Oh sorry I didn't understand I thought you meant to keep the same labels. Let me try what you have suggested would you put it as an answer in case others have the same issue? & so I can accept it of course :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, you're using D3's scales to determine where bars are created. Scales map input to output values, i.e. the same input value will be mapped to the same output value. To get different outputs, you have to provide different inputs. That is, your code is fine, but the data needs to be changed/amended. You could for example add another attribute:

```
output = [
  { day : "M", frequency : 1, ID: "1"},
  { day : "M", frequency : 2, ID: "2"}
  { day : "T", frequency : 3, ID: "3"}
  { day : "T", frequency : 4, ID: "4"}
  { day : "M", frequency : 5, ID: "5"}
]

// more code

var xValue = function(d) { return d.ID; },
```

The rest of the code can remain as is.